# Haskell on Windows Setup

Tags: windows, haskell

Unfortunately I don't have access to a *nix box at work or at home.  The only way I can play with Haskell is on windows.  Anyone here using Haskell on Windows? What's your setup?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've used Haskell on Windows, but only when forced to.  Not because the combination Haskell+Windows is particularly bad, but just because I don't really like Windows.

My setup was basically the following:

- GHC
- [Vim](http://vim.org/)
- [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/)
- [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console)
- [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/)
- [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/)

As you can see I was trying to get an environment that was as similar to Unix as possible (without using cygwin, because I find it utterly confusing).  Vim is my favourite editor.  The reason for Visual Studio was that the C environment shipped with GHC doesn't cover *all* of Win32API.  I used CMake to get a decent build environment.

Comment: The Windows "dos box" is a pile of crap, IMNSHO :-)  Console is a properly resizable terminal window.  MinGW does come with a terminal, but it mixes in some Unix-ness that isn't always desired.

Comment: Add the powershell to the mix to get a decent shell, and you got a pretty strong developing environment for Haskell on windows.

Answer (score 40):

DISCLAIMER: What's below was valid in Oct, 2013. So there is a good chance it might get outdated soon. Your edits and comments are welcome.

This is what I have done in order to get Haskell set up on my Windows 7 x64

#### 1. Install Haskell Platform

Download and install the Haskell Platform from http://www.haskell.org/platform/windows.html

#### 2. Install Sublime Text 3

Download and install Sublime Text 3 from http://www.sublimetext.com/3

#### 3. Enable the Package manager in Sublime

1. Run Sublime
2. Open the console: `View` >> `Show console`
3. Paste the following code to the console and hit Enter (according to [this](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation)):

`import urllib.request,os; pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); urllib.request.install_opener( urllib.request.build_opener( urllib.request.ProxyHandler()) ); open(os.path.join(ipp, pf), 'wb').write(urllib.request.urlopen( 'http://sublime.wbond.net/' + pf.replace(' ','%20')).read())`

4. Open the command palette: `Tools` >> `Command palette`
5. In the command palette popup type in: `Package Control: Install Package`
6. Select the package: `SublimeHaskell`

#### 4. Install Haskell tools

Cabal is the standard package manager for Haskell. What you need to do is:

1. Start a console with administrative permissions
2. Run:

   ```
   cabal install cabal-install
   cabal update
   cabal install aeson
   cabal install haskell-src-exts
   cabal install ghc-mod
   cabal install cmdargs
   cabal install haddock
   ```

#### 5. Install hdevtools

You can NOT install hdevtools on Windows by running: cabal instal hdevtools. What you need to do instead is:

1. Download the source code of hdevtools for Windows from https://github.com/mvoidex/hdevtools*
   (* Currently does not work with GHC 7.10. [See this fork](https://github.com/flashus/hdevtools) for building with GHC 7.10 and above)
2. Unpack it to some folder
3. Go to that folder and run:

   ```
   runhaskell Setup.hs configure --user
   runhaskell Setup.hs build
   runhaskell Setup.hs install
   ```
4. Watch for the path (in the console output) where the hdevtools have been installed. You will need this path when setting up the SublimeHaskell plugin in Sublime. The path should look something like this: `C:\Users\Aleksey Bykov\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin` where `Aleksey Bykov` is the name of the current user.

#### 6. Setting up the SublimeHaskell plugin in Sublime:

1. Start Sublime
2. Go `Preferences` >> `Package settings` >> `SumblimeHaskell` >> `Settings - User`
3. Make sure you configuration looks like:

   ```
   {
       "add_to_PATH":
       [
           "C:/Users/Aleksey Bykov/AppData/Roaming/cabal/bin/"
       ],
       "enable_hdevtools": true
   }
   ```

where `C:/Users/Aleksey Bykov/AppData/Roaming/cabal/bin/` is that path (you got at step 5) where hdevtools (all all other toolls have been installed)
4. Save the file and restart Sublime

#### 7. Hello world

1. Start Sublime
2. Create a new file and save it immediately as `hello-world.hs`
3. Put the following code there:

   ```
   main::IO()
   main = putStrLn "Hello world!"
   ```
4. Build and run by going `Tools` >> `Build` x 2 times (first it builds, second it runs)

#### 8. See also

There is another great article: http://howistart.org/posts/haskell/1

Comment: This should be the accepted answer imo. As of 2014-05-02 it still works exactly like outlined above except one small caveat - if you're running the latest Haskell Platform installer you might not be able to run `cabal install haddock`, instead run:
 `cabal install haddock --constraint=haddock==2.13.2.1`.

Comment: Most of what you and @AndersHolmström said works but for me sublime was not finding hdevtools or the other cabal packages I had installed, turns out it didn't have permission to access cabal's bin folder, probably because I downloaded and ran the portable version of sublime. to solve it I just had to run sublime as admin, don't know if this is safe but it solved the problem for me. as an aside everytime I start sublime it does the task "loading standard modules cabal" for a while is this expected behaviour?

Comment: I agree with @AndersHolmström - i think this is the best answer, however i think the cabal installer must have been upgraded as i didn't have any trouble with hdevtools today. Once i had installed the haskell environment all i needed to do was open cmd.exe and run 'cabal install' and it resolved and installed hdevtools for me. after that i configured the sublimehaskell plugin, and it now all works!

Comment: got deprecated this year.

Answer (score 10):

[Haskell Platform](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/) is now more or less the standard distribution of haskell, and it has a windows installer.

Comment: The main advantage of Haskell Platform over plain GHC installation is that the Platform contains precompiled packages which is hard to compile on Windows because they require MSys toolchain.

Comment: Sadly, Haskell Platform is deprecated as of 2022 - see https://www.haskell.org/platform/

Answer (score 1):

[GHC](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/index.html) is a state-of-the-art, open source, compiler and interactive environment for the functional language Haskell.

There is a [Windows installer for GHC](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_642.html#windows), but it for Version 6.4.2 .

A Windows `.exe` (not an `.msi` installer) for version 6.10.1 is at http://www.haskell.org/ghc/dist/6.10.1/
It is not clear when the current (GHC 6.10.1) version will offer a Windows installer.

Answer (score 1):

No one seems to have mentioned [Atom](https://atom.io/) yet, which I've been using for a few weeks now. It's not quite as stable and mature as ST3 yet, but it looks promising and offers cabal (partial) and ghc-mod (good) integration via plugins.

Answer (score 1):

How to install Haskell in windows10 :

Step01: open windows powershell (run as administrator) and run the following command as instructed:

command 1 : command = Get-ExecutionPolicy, If it returns "Restricted" then run this command = Set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned

command 2 : command = Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
(note: type "Y" whenever it asks and click enter )

step02:run the following command(in windows powershell (run as administrator)):
command = choco install haskell-dev haskell-stack
(note: type "Y" whenever it asks and click enter )
after running this command close the powershell

step03: verification if you did everything right:
open command prompt and run the following code:
command = ghc --version
output should be = The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 9.2.1
(minimize the command prompt)

how to run a simple code and get output :
step01: open command prompt and run the following commands one by one:
cd \
cls
mkdir dev
cd dev
cls
notepad hello.hs
notepad will open and now write the following program and save it :
program:
main = do
print "My first Haskell program"
name <- getLine
print ("Hello, " ++name)

write this and save
step 02 : to run the program open command prompt that was minimized before and run the following commands:
commands=

1. ghc hello.hs
2. hello
   You should get the output as : My first Haskell program.

To use the same in vs code: after you do the above steps open(open with vs code) hello.hs file in c drive dev folder and then in extentions install Haskell Syntax Highlighting  and run the same commands in terminal choose command prompt as default rather than windows powershell.
(note before you open the .hs in vs code make sure you delete every other file expect the hello.hs file)

Answer (score 0):

I recall using [hugs](http://www.haskell.org/hugs/) with some success a while ago. I was just playing around though.

Comment: The problem with hugs is that is... well a bit out of data. I was using ghc and then I had to come back on hugs for university course. I felt how many things is missing (to be honest - even downgrade from 6.10 to 6.8 was felt).

Answer (score 0):

I based on Magnus solution. I have to state that I'm normally GNU/Linux user and I had to port low level packages ([like this one](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ioctl)).

- [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console)
- [Haskell Platform](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/) (it contains [GHC](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/) and, on Windows, [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/))
- [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) with [X](http://www.x.org/wiki/)
- [XEmacs](http://www.xemacs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Installing it on windows is much more difficult and painful that on a Mac (as it is with almost all dev software). That being said, here is the simplest way to set up a Haskell environment on Windows 10:

Open Powershell as Aministrator (right click, and "Run as Administrator").

1 In Powershell, check your execution policy as follows:

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy
```

2 If you get "Restricted", you need to change it. Execute this command:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process
```

3 When you get a question prompt, type:

```
A
```

Hit Enter.

4 Verify your policy again with Get-ExecutionPolicy. Now your policy should be "Bypass".

5 Double check that you have Chocolatey:

```
choco
```

6 Install Haskell:

```
choco install haskell-dev
```

It takes a while..

7 Start coding in Haskell!

http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out

Answer (score -1):

Or You could partition your hard-drive a duel boot between linux and windows :)

Doesn't answer your question, but it is an alternative.

Comment: I second this suggestion.

I've just install a new partition with Fedora 11, and Haskell. It took me about an hour (most of which was just machine time).

A direct Windows installation of Haskell requires Cygwin, or MinGW. I've used both of these in the past. They work OK, but require a lot of fiddling, and, last time I checked, didn't work under Vista.

If you've never installed a Linux partition, it may seem scary, but I think you'll find it easier than Cygwin or MinGW + Haskell.

Comment: I find this kind of answers counter-productive. That's great you use Linux. Or FreeBSD. Or OS X, or Solaris, or Haiku, or whatever. But this is just annoying to ignore "The only way I can play with Haskell is on windows" and suggest otherwise.
The actual problem I find with this kind of answers is that they do not provide *any* value to the OP or the SO community.

Comment: @kgadek Except, if he's got a PC, with windows on it, he can make it both windows and linux. It's a valid alternative that he may not have fully realised was possible. Though, 7 years later, my advice now, should he come across something that ideally requires *nix, would be to use a vm, and maybe even something like Vagrant. But that's neither here nor there.

Answer (score -1):

You could install Sun's VirtualBox, and install Linux on it.