# Installing Haskell on Windows

Tags: haskell

This is what I have done so far...
I am following instructions posted here [Haskell on Windows Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304614/haskell-on-windows-setup)

Step 1: Install Haskell Platform

Step 2: Install a SublimeText3

Step 3: Enabled the Package manager in Sublime
            3a.  Tools -> Command Palette
            3b. Type in Package Control: Install Package
            3c. Select SublimeHaskell

Step 4: In cmd ran,

```
       cabal install cabal-install --user
       cabal update
       cabal install aeson --user
       cabal install haskell-src-exts --user
       cabal install ghc-mod --user
       canal install haddock-2.13.2.1 --user
```

Step 5: I downloaded the source code of hdevtools
           runhaskell Setup.hs configure --user
This is what I get

```
      Configuring hdevtools-0.1.0.5...
      Setup.hs: At least the following dependencies are missing:
      unix - any
```

Can someone in detail explain how to fix this?
Thx

Comment: See step 5 [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19611239/1394393), I believe.

Comment: You've already installed haskell. `hdevtools` requires the `unix` package, which is difficult (at best) to install on windows. I've never found `hdevtools` or the like to be particularly useful, but if you really need it, first install [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), then try `cabal install unix -v2`.

Comment: jpmc26, that is the site that I was referring to...

Comment: @user3569927 Try [this fork](https://github.com/mvoidex/hdevtools) of hdevtools that works on Windows.  I installed it from this repository just this week.

Comment: Consider installing Linux as well as windows (on an OracleBox virtual machine, or dual boot). It is useful for a fallback when you hit something that isn't supported on Windows. I often switch between the two operating systems when Haskelling. Or for zero-install you could even run up a linux instance in the cloud, and if you remember to shut it down each time you finish it will cost you almost nothing.

Comment: @bheklilr, how do you install the Windows hdevtools please? The readme just says to do `cabal install hdevtools`, but that will just attempt to install the regular hdevtools, which isn't very helpful.

Comment: @dan-gph If you download the version from the repo I linked above (granted it hasn't seen development since Nov '14 so good luck on compatibility, although there is a [pull request for 7.10 support](https://github.com/mvoidex/hdevtools/pull/2)), then inside the folder with the `hdevtools.cabal` file you just run `cabal install` then it should work.  I would recommend building it inside a sandbox and then copying the built binary over to your `~/.cabal` folder, it helps keep your system install of Haskell clean.

Comment: @bheklilr, thanks, that is useful to know. It turns out that I can use hsdev instead in Sublime Text, it seems. I gather that hsdev is something similar to hdevtools.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed above, the was that `hdevtools` requires the `unix` package, which, as the name implies is not supported on windows, and does not support either Cygwin or MinGW.

So `hdevtools` is, sadly, not buildable on windows machines.