# Is there a standardized setup for Haskell on windows that all packages must support?

Tags: windows, haskell, installation, package

I have to develop Haskell on Windows.
I need libraries that have a .configure file so I need *nix-like support.

There are multiple options for *nix-like support, like Cygwin, UnxUtils, Windows Services for UNIX, UWin, MinGW, MSYS, MSYS2, ...
Unfortunately, I discovered that not all packages support all options for *nix-like support.
Since I only need *nix-like support to build packages, to me all *nix-like support is equal and I am wondering:

**Is there a standardized setup for Haskell on windows that all packages must support?**

If not, what setup for Haskell on Windows will work with most package?

Of course, I have consulted the answer of [Haskell on Windows setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304614/haskell-on-windows-setup), yet the answers seem outdated. For example, Cygwin is mentioned, yet is no longer supported by some package, see e.g. [failing package install on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38570323/failing-cabal-install-missingh-and-network-on-windows).

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Pierre

Comment: There is certainly no anything that _all_ packages _must_ support. All Stackage LTS packages, perhaps... but if you want it really foolproof you'll probably have to use something like Docker.

Answer (score 0):

Officially, Cygwin is not supported by GHC (and personally I don't like it very much).

MSYS2 is used to build GHC on Windows, and the packages that require configure support, such as network etc.

So I'd say you'd get more mileage out of MSYS2 since that's what the Compiler is developed on Windows.